# How to add files to project on google code?

Tags: svn, project-management, google-code

I normally organize my project in multiple files. Now, for the first time I have created a  project at code.google.com/hosting.

How to add files to the project?

The project has got directory structure and many files. I want them to be visible under **trunk** (like it is in other projects).

NOTE: I am novice in this area (I have no clue about what to do). I am searching for an UPLOAD button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a source code management system to be able to do that. Google Code typically uses subversion. Either download the commandline version or a GUI wrapper like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/). Then, you can upload all your project files.

- [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/GettingStarted)
- [Project Hosting FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/FAQ)
- [Google Code blog](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/search/label/project%20hosting)

Answer (score 1):

Google Code uses Subversion for source control:

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/GettingStarted#Working_with_your_Source_Repository_on_the_Source_Tab